# How to convert a complex datasheet into a usabale dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

So I have the following google sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GAH6Cb8JuloDAiTIGnEr9GtPPyHWXMpOLV6nHNSgcoM/edit#gid=1324085625

This sheet is a school timetable and what I have to do is read some fitered data like for example name of the teacher and when does he has classrom or name of the classroom and when it's ocupied. I'm free to filter how ever I want then I have to converted the filtered result into a pdf. My problem is how do I make this data into a dataframe that can be fitered! I tried with the libraries gspread and pandas and made the dataframe but the data is unusable and can't manipulate it. From the research I've done usualy the dataframes have a header and the data is nicely organized, in my case the timetable I think it's not structered to be used that way! How would you aproache a problem like this and make the data in these sheet easy to play with? I need an ideea!

[image: csv example]What I did is I converted the sheet into a data frame using pandas and gspread but it is not usabale in my situation!

Comment: Please show the code you tried, but if the file has no structure, then you need to create the structure yourself. Only then will a dataframe work. For example, load each line as one column since newline delimited files are still "structured". The problem arises when `\n` is part of the columns

Comment: Alternatively, use Google Sheets Python API to parse out cells without exporting to a CSV file

Comment: Ok thank you I'm gonna try your ideeas and make an update!  I didn't now you could structure  the file!

Comment: From what you've shown, you really cant. Not all spreadsheets can be parsed as tables. Especially when you start merging cells and offset other values across diagonal rows/columns

Comment: Ok so is there any other solution like filtering with the google sheets api ? Like stop using dataframes and focusing only on the api somehow? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by filter. You can select ranges of cells. Then yes, you can iterate over a range to get cell text and conditionally parse it... Refer the gsheets docs